# Reverse a string in JavaScript: Why is my answer not passing the test?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, reverse

I am struggling with a JavaScript test, my answer isn't passing and I can't see why?

Here's the question:

> Write a function that returns the reverse of a given string. Although many languages have a built in function to reverse a string, you should do it manually, building up the output character by character.
>   For example, "Hello" returns "olleH"

And this is what I have so far...

```js
stringReverse = function(input) {
  // Your code goes here
  var inputA = input.split('');
  var inputL = inputA.length;
  var beta = new Array(inputL);
  for (var i=0; i<inputL; i++) {
    var alpha = inputA.pop();
    beta.splice(i,1,alpha);
  }
  var newStr = beta.join('');
  return console.log(newStr);
};
```

My output looks correct, however it isn't passing the tests. I get the following message:

> Started
>
> olleH
>   FA
>   F
>   F
>   Failures:
>   1) SolutionTests Test1
>     Message:
>       Expected undefined to equal 'olleH'.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Expected undefined to equal 'olleH'.
>           at Object. (/sandboxes/deer/SolutionSpec.js:7:40)
>   2) SolutionTests Test2
>     Message:
>       Expected undefined to equal 'A'.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Expected undefined to equal 'A'.
>           at Object. (/sandboxes/deer/SolutionSpec.js:11:36)
>   3) SolutionTests Test3
>     Message:
>       Expected undefined to equal ''.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Expected undefined to equal ''.
>           at Object. (/sandboxes/deer/SolutionSpec.js:15:35)
>   3 specs, 3 failures
>   Finished in 0.014 seconds

Comment: P.S. input is already defined in the test.

Answer (score 2):

```
return console.log(newStr);
```

This returns the `undefined` value. I think you mean:

```
return newStr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to `return newStr` instead of `return console.log(newStr)`.  Currently your programs prints the correct answer, but doesn't return anything.  The test is looking only at the return value, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

So heres your issue, your doing return console.log(newStr). This runs console.log which does not have an output and that returns that lack of an output hence the undefined. Just simply do return newStr;

Answer (score 2):

its because you are console logging the return instead of returning newStr.

try this:

```
stringReverse = function(input) { 
   var inputA = input.split('');
   var inputL = inputA.length;
   var beta = new Array(inputL);
   for (var i=0; i<inputL; i++) {
     var alpha = inputA.pop();
     beta.splice(i,1,alpha);
   }
   var newStr = beta.join('');
   return newStr;
};
```

you can also do this in only one line:

```
stringReverse = function(input) {
   return input.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you return the return value of console.log which is undefined!

Change:

```
return console.log(newStr);
```

to

```
console.log(newStr);
return newStr;
```

Greetings!